# Input 0 of layer "dense_24" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1, but received input with shape (None, 28)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

```
from PIL import Image
user_test = filename
col = Image.open(user_test)
gray = col.convert('L')
bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<100 else 255, '1')
bw.save("bw_image.jpg")
bw
img_array = cv2.imread("bw_image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img_array = cv2.bitwise_not(img_array)
print(img_array.size)
plt.imshow(img_array, cmap = plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
img_size = 28
print(img_array)
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_size,img_size))
print(new_array)
print(new_array)
plt.imshow(new_array, cmap = plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
user_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(new_array, axis = 1)
print(user_test);
predicted = model.predict([[user_test]])
 a = predicted[0][0]
 for i in range(0,10):
   b = predicted[0][i]
   print("Probability Distribution for",i,b)

 print("The Predicted Value is",np.argmax(predicted[0]))
```

This is my code for predicting a character from the image. I converted the image into black and white, normalized it, and made a prediction. However, I received the error as above while making the prediction. In the line `predicted = model.predict([[user_test]])`
I am new to it. Please help me, somebody.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: why are you wrapping `user_test` in square brackets?

Comment: Hi @Alisha, please let us know the output of `user_test.shape`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the flag raised in your code :

**img_size = 28**  should be given as img_size = (28,1)

Which is what the error is clearly indicating : The axis numbered -1 should be having shape of 1 .

The application as mentioned by you is for semantic image segmentation . You can use pytesseract comfortably for doing that

Hence your code should now look like,
As I dont have your image, I'm adding one of my own.

Sample Image :

[image: Example Image]

```
# importing the libraries 
import cv2 
import pytesseract 
  
# setting the path of pytesseract exe 
# you have to write the location of 
# on which your tesseract was installed 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
  
# Now we will read the image in our program 
# you have to put your image path in place of photo.jpg 
img = cv2.imread('photo.jpg') 
  
# Our image will read as BGR format, 
# So we will convert in RGB format because  
# tesseract can only read in RGB format 
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
  
# For getting the text and number from image 
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img)) 
  
# For displaying the original image 
cv2.imshow("result", img) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output :

`Input 0`